# Percentage difference of winding measurements

Tags: resistance, testing, insulation

I am trying to learn more about the proper winding measurement of power transformers.
In this regard I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HIEIoa4NKA&list=LL&index=2.
In this I came across to the fact that in the industry there is guidance regarding the percentage difference regarding the windings measurements.
Could you please help me understand how are the bellow values calculated - % Diff of 4.444, 3.362, 4.350 and 3.888. This appears in the video attached at 29:15.

[image]

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the smallest and largest values for each tap, expressed as a % of the mean almost matches the values you give: 4.441%, 3.643%, 4.419%, 3.884%

However, I can't get an exact match with the quoted values.  Perhaps the calculation is done with more significant figures than shown.

Comment: How did you calculate for those figures ?

Comment: For each row average the three readings.  Then subtract the smallest reading from the biggest reading.  Finally divide the difference by the average.